# Azure App service Linux install dependencies

Tags: linux, azure, .net-7.0

I have an API written in .NET 7 that must run on a Linux service app. I made a startup script to install external lib.

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update && \

apt-get install -y libc6 -f -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0 && \

apt-get install -y \ libicu-dev \ libharfbuzz0b \ libfontconfig1 \ libfreetype6

dotnet Api.dll
```

My problem is that my script is never executed. It is always ignored. Before when my app service was in .NET 5, it worked correctly.

I call my script like this. It’s in/home/site/wwwroot

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about how you run your app? What's the startup command of the App Service? etc

Answer (score 0):

Is your script called `run.sh`?

If so: there is a typo in the Startup Command.
It says `run;sh` instead of `run.sh`

Comment: Yes my script is called run.sh
I corrected in azure but still the same. It is not taken into account
it is in/home/site/wwwroot

Comment: AFAIK, the root of the project in the App Service is `home/site/wwwroot`, so the Startup Command will look there for the file. Are you sure the shell script is deployed in the App Service? Can you find the shell script locally in the `bin` folder when you build the project?

Comment: yes it is present in the bin folder that I generate and I connect in ftp to the service and I see it well

Comment: Hm strange. Do you see anything in the application/webserver logging?

Comment: Azure generate this command when start app : Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -bindPort2  -userStartupCommand 'home/site/wwwroot/run.sh'